# Ansible mysql grant

Tags: mysql, database, ansible

I want to grant privilege on a db(`test_db`) to a user(`test_user`) using Ansible. My command is as shown below.

```
grant all PRIVILEGES on <test_db>.* to <test_user>@'localhost';
```

How will I execute the command using Ansible.

Comment: What have you tried so far with [mysql_user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html)?

Answer (score 9):

You could do it like this:

```
- name: Set mysql user privileges
  mysql_user:
    name=user_name
    priv="dbname.*:ALL"
    state=present
```

Of course you can interpolate variables, like the username, db name, etc...

Answer (score 3):

```
- name: "Create user {{ user }}"
  mysql_user:
    name: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    host: localhost
    state: present
    update_password: on_create
    priv: "{{ dbname }}.*:ALL"
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Solutions works

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.